# What is the outer function variable and outer function in this closure?

Tags: javascript

new to Javascript, I am going through closures and just wondering What the outer function variable and outer function is in this closure?

```js
function hello(name, age) {
  var message = name + ", who is " + age + " years old, says hi!";

  return function sayhi() {
    console.log(message);
  };
}

var sayHelloToJohn = hello("John", 33);

sayHelloToJohn();
```

Comment: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the outer function variable is `message` and its params `name` `age`, and the outer function is `hello`.

It's about their relative with the function `sayHi`. So `sayHi` can use its outer function variable, it knows `message` and prints it out as you can see.